# Matching up the color of secondary data with the primary data in ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

In my plot below, I was wondering how to match up the color of the dashed, black vertical lines from the last `geom_vline()` call with the color of the regression lines from `geom_smooth()` call (i.e., color of `groups`)?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/cw.csv')
data$groups <- as.factor(data$groups)

g_means <- data %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarise(m = mean(x), .groups = 'drop')


ggplot(data) + aes(x, y, color = groups)+ geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F,formula ='y ~ x') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0, mean(data$x)), color = "magenta", linetype = c(1, 3)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(data = g_means, color = groups), xintercept = g_means$m, linetype = rep(2, 3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but i think that if you place `xintercept` not as an `aes`, it will ignore the mapping argument, so you need to place it inside the `aes()`.

```
ggplot(data) + aes(x, y, color = groups)+ geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F,formula ='y ~ x') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0, mean(data$x)), color = "magenta", linetype = c(1, 3)) + 
  geom_vline(data=g_means, aes(color=groups, xintercept=m), linetype = rep(2, 3))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When I run into `ggplot` trouble, I look at the help page for the function. In this case it appears that the data argument should be outside the mapping (`aes`) argument. You should also deliver just the column name to the xintercept value inside the mapping rather than trying to pull it in from outside the data argument. So this appears to deliver what you expect:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data) + aes(x, y, color = groups)+ geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F,formula ='y ~ x') +
    geom_vline(xintercept = c(0, mean(data$x)), color = "magenta", linetype = c(1, 3)) + 
    geom_vline( data = g_means, aes(color=groups, xintercept=m), linetype = rep(2L, 3))
```

[image]